# Does OSM2po handle squares and places?

Tags: routing, postgis-2.0, area, osm2po, places

OSM2po is converting data from OSM to postgresql. But how is it handled with places or squares? Not every places, square has pedestrian way routes on it. But for routing I need nodes and pedestrians can walk through places without restriction, if there are no obstacles between. But we can consider only "empty" places. Therefore the shortest distance is to walk through the place. How is osm2po handling area=yes or highway=footway for areas, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

highway=footway is no problem. Please have a look into the osm2po.config file.
Areas (Polygons) cannot be taken into account.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was asking because of this website http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.openstreetmap.region.at/5213 and because I would need routing through places and sqaures. Is it possible to add this on my own to osm2po?

Comment: Indeed, this is a problem. In reality every public place is somehow connected to streets or at least pedestrian areas. Most routers depend on networks and cannot guess or interpret ways in between.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it now on my own, by adding information to the osm2po database table, with my own implementation. Therefore I know now which place is for pedestrians and which not. So I can run my routing software through this.

Comment: This answer got flagged up due to its brevity.  To help future readers would you be able to expand upon your answer?  For example, what was the additional software that led to your solution?